# help finding the inverse of this function

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=x^3 - \frac4x$$

Find the value of the inverse for $x=6$.

The answer is $2$ and I'm having problems finding the inverse function because there are two variables of different powers.

Comment: When what is six? The input of the inverse is 6?

Comment: Sorry I meant when x is six so yes. The Input.

Comment: Do you want a closed form for the inverse function? This might be difficult. Otherwise note that $2^3-4/2=6$ so obviously $f^{-1}(6) = 2.$ The inverse exists because $f'(x) > 0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why that's so obvious. I'm sure once you tell me I'll go oh....  And yes I've been attempting to find the closed form but it a proving to be quite difficult.

Comment: $f(2)=6 \Longrightarrow f^{-1}(6)=2$

Comment: @METEORITES If you want $f^{-1}(6)$, I would say that you were looking for $f^{-1}$ when $\mathbf{y}$ equals $6$, not $x$.  I find it helpful to visualize inverses by using $x$ to plug into the original function, and $y$ into the inverse function.  Anyway, the fact $f(2)=6$ is not sufficient to say $f^{-1}(6)=2$, since there is a negative $x$-value at which $f$ takes the value $6$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is the following:

Let's call the output of the inverse function $x$ (i.e. our answer is $x$)when the input is $6$, so we have $f^{-1}(6)=x$. Now I'll "take the function" of both sides: 
$$f(f^{-1}(6))=f(x) \implies 6=f(x)$$ So you need to solve the equation $6=x^3-4/x$ which happens to have two solutions. One of which is $x=2$, the other is $x \approx -0.638$

By the way, this function's inverse isn't exactly defined because the function itself doesn't pass the *horizontal line test*.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse is given by swapping the $x$ and $y$, so:

$$x=y^3-\frac4y$$

This can't be expressed in terms of $f^{-1}(x)=\cdots$, because it doesn't pass the Vertical Line Test.

The inverse at $x=6$ is found by solving the following equation:

$$6=y^3-\frac4y$$

This gives $y=2$, so the inverse at $x=6$ is $2$.

Comment: Not exactly, see my comment to the original question.

Comment: Are you sure that $f^{-1}(y)=y^3-4/y$? If I calculate $f(1)$ I get $-3$ but $(-3)^3 -4/(-3)\neq 1$.

Comment: The inverse is correct.